# Connect to Wifi without Ethernet?

Tags: server, wireless, internet, 19.10

I have installed Ubuntu Server 19.10 and I cannot connect to the internet. I do not have any ethernet ports, I only have a Wifi chip. Wireless Tools, Net Tools, NetworkManager, and wpasupplicant are not installed. The network I am trying to connect to has WPA2 security.

Comment: I’ve not used Ubuntu Server 19.10 but do have an 18.04 running that connects to my wifi home network. I just had to configure something called netplan to get it connecting. Visit https://netplan.io/ for info

Comment: @PonJar I do not have ethernet, like explained, and it tends to get quite annoying to install NetworkManager. I found a way to install wireless-tools, net-tools, and wpa_supplicant, by using a USB.

Comment: It’s a few months ago that I set this up so I could be wrong but I don’t think I had to install any thing. Look at the examples page off the link above. There’s an example for Connecting to a WPA Personal wireless network. I definitely followed that example

Comment: Ok, I got NetworkManager on. Thanks for letting me know!

Comment: I don't think you need NetworkManager. networkd will do fine. I'll paste my config in the answer box.

Comment: @Erik Pokladowski Please help others by writing this as an answer then clicking on the answer's checkmark so others can see it was your accepted solution.

Answer (score 0):

This is my Ubuntu 18.04 Netplan config. It's a .yaml file in /etc/netplan/ See netplan.io for the commands to apply the config. Your wifi adapter may not be wlp1s0. You will need to find that on your system. I'm using a static ip address on my network of 192.168.0.66. yours may be different.

```
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  wifis:
    wlp1s0:
      dhcp4: no
      dhcp6: no
      addresses: [192.168.0.66/24]
      gateway4: 192.168.0.1
      nameservers:
        addresses: [192.168.0.1, 8.8.8.8]
      access-points:
        "MySSID":
          password: "MyPassword"
      optional: true
```

Comment: Please forgive my use of an image. Pasting the contents of my config file did not format correctly

Comment: Please copy and paste the content of the file. Then highlight the whole pasted connect and click on the { } icon above the edit question window to**format as code**

Comment: Thanks @user68186, that is really easy to format as code so I have learnt something :). For some reason I've never managed to do that successfully before. I've been clicking the { } and trying to insert the code.